# UIImagePickerController Image Type in swift 3

Tags: iphone, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode8.2

I am using the UIImagePickerController to select the image from the gallery and camera . I am using the following delegates

```
    public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
    imageView = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage
    profilePhoto.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    profilePhoto.image = imageView
    let imageData: Data =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(profilePhoto.image!)!
    self.base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString()
    dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
  }

  public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    print("Cancel")
  }
```

I am successfully setting the image in the profile view . But i need to know the format of the image selected through gallery and camera i.e whether it is .jpeg or .png as I need to send the type to the Backend. Please do tell how to know the format of the image

Comment: I would suggest is better/easier to let the backend infer the type of image (.jpeg or .png). If you **must** send a type, my suggestion would be to send always `.png` that will work for both (jpeg doesn't support transparency).

Answer (score 0):

For the camera you can decide using
let jpgImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView, 1.0)
and
let pngImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView)